# KafkaMirrorMaker Is returning invalid syntax expression for whitelist option

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

`kafka-mirror-maker.bat --consumer.config C:\\Users\\P9168308\\Documents\\consumerconfig.properties --producer.config C:\\Users\\P9168308\\Documents\\producerconfig.properties --whitelist "^Data_SfmcOfferAllocation_BEAM_Pluto_v1x00$"`

I am using the above expression for transferring data . It is giving below error

```
ERROR Invalid expression syntax: ^Data_SfmcOfferAllocation_BEAM_Pluto_v1x00$ (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$)

[2022-04-15 08:11:54,921] ERROR [mirrormaker-thread-0] Mirror maker thread failure due to  (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread)

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidGroupIdException: To use the group management or offset commit APIs, you must provide a valid group.id in the consumer configuration.
[2022-04-15 08:11:54,932] 

ERROR [mirrormaker-thread-0] Mirror maker thread exited abnormally, stopping the whole mirror maker. (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Anyone Coming across this issue org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidGroupIdException: To use the group management or offset commit APIs, you must provide a valid group.id in the consumer configuration. [2022-04-15 08:11:54,932] this was the reason for that error. If we provide a group id then the error is not happening

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this script is deprecated in favor of `connect-mirror`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).